# Correct way to launch xdg desktop portal under bare WM setup?

Tags: x11, xorg, window-manager, flatpak, xdg

### Context

I'm running Void Linux with X11. I'm not using any desktop environment or display manager. I simply type `startx` from tty to launch X11, and `~/.xinitrc` launches BSPWM, polybar, and all the other apps that I need.

### Problem

I use a lot of flatpak apps, which rely on xdg desktop portal to provide the filechooser. When I launch X11 for the first time, everything works correctly. But if I quit X11 and re-launch it from the tty a second time, the filechooser is broken in all flatpak apps. For example, pressing `CTRL+O` in Librewolf *does* bring up the filechooser, but it refuses to actually open any of the files I select. Similarly, trying to download a file brings up the filechooser, but, after that, never actually downloads the file. In short:

1. I Launch X11
2. Everything works fine
3. I decide to kill X11 and exit to tty
4. I Launch X11 again
5. Filechooser is now broken in all flatpak apps

### Current solution

My intuition told me that there must be some process that gets started with X11, but not properly terminated when X11 exits. My solution was to put this bombshell of a one-liner at the start and end of my `~/.xinitrc` that essentially nukes everything related to desktop portals:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep '/usr/libexec/xdg-' | awk '{print $2}')
```

This seems to solve the problem. Now, filechoosers work correctly even after restarting X11.

### My question

My current solution feels like to total hack. Killing processes by grepping their name, really? It feels like I'm doing something wrong. Surely there must be an explicit list of processes that I need to kill when exiting X11, or some sort of supervisor that should kill them automatically? In short, **what is the correct way to run xdg desktop portal in a no-DE / no-DM setup**, that doesn't result in breakage when restarting X11?

### More context

I actually have two files responsible for starting X11. The first is the traditional `~/.xinitrc`, and the second is a script I made called `launch_de.sh` that is exec'd by `~/.xinitrc`. Additionally, the xdg killer one-liner is also in a separate file called `kill_all_xdg_processes.sh` The contents are as follows:

```bash
# file: ~/.xinitrc

#!/bin/sh

set -e

kill_all_xdg_portals.sh || true

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi

export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx 
export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx 
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx 
export XIM_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/fcitx 

export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1

xrdb -merge ~/.config/X11/Xresources
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr

exec dbus-launch launch_de.sh
```

```bash
# file: launch_de.sh

#!/bin/sh

kill_all_xdg_portals.sh

fcitx5 &

pipewire &
pipewire-pulse &
wireplumber &

polybar &
sxhkd &
nm-applet &
mpd --no-daemon &
xss-lock lock_noblank.sh &

xmodmap ~/.config/X11/Xmodmap

bspwm

kill_all_xdg_portals.sh
```

```bash
# file: kill_all_xdg_portals.sh

#!/bin/sh
kill $(ps aux | grep '/usr/libexec/xdg-' | awk '{print $2}')
```

#### Lingering processes

For more information, here is the output of `ps aux | grep xdg` at various stages (this is WITHOUT running the `kill_all_xdg_portals.sh` script)

##### Immediately after boot, before launching X11

```
renzev  1426  0.0  0.0   6560  2432 tty1     S+   11:51   0:00 grep xdg
```

##### Having launched X11

```
renzev  1598  0.0  0.1 470404 12672 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
renzev  1610  0.0  0.0 529392  5632 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
renzev  1615  0.0  0.0 305608  5248 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
renzev  1630  0.1  0.2 412324 22564 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
renzev  1776  0.0  0.0   6560  2560 pts/1    S+   11:52   0:00 grep xdg
```

##### Having lanuched a flatpak app (librewolf)

```
renzev  1598  0.0  0.1 470404 12672 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
renzev  1610  0.0  0.0 529392  5632 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
renzev  1615  0.0  0.0 305608  5248 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
renzev  1630  0.1  0.2 412324 22564 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
renzev  1899  0.0  0.0   2568  1664 ?        S    11:52   0:00 bwrap --args 43 xdg-dbus-proxy --args=45
renzev  1900  0.1  0.0 231984  4992 ?        Sl   11:52   0:00 xdg-dbus-proxy --args=45
renzev  2176  0.0  0.0   6560  2560 pts/1    S+   11:52   0:00 grep xdg
```

##### After exiting X11

```
renzev  1598  0.0  0.1 739376 12116 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
renzev  1610  0.0  0.0 751620  5888 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
renzev  1615  0.0  0.0 306348  6272 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
renzev  3243  0.0  0.0   6560  2432 tty1     S+   11:55   0:00 grep xdg
```

##### After launching X11 a second time

```
renzev  1598  0.0  0.1 740744 13012 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
renzev  1610  0.0  0.0 751620  5888 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
renzev  1615  0.0  0.0 306348  6272 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
renzev  3382  0.1  0.1 470404 12800 ?        Sl   11:56   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
renzev  3395  0.0  0.0 305608  5120 ?        Sl   11:56   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
renzev  3412  0.1  0.2 412324 22276 ?        Sl   11:56   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
renzev  3556  0.0  0.0   6560  2432 pts/1    S+   11:56   0:00 grep xdg
```

#### After launching librewolf a second time (now the filechooser is broken)

```
renzev  1598  0.0  0.1 740744 13012 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
renzev  1610  0.0  0.0 751620  5888 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
renzev  1615  0.0  0.0 306348  6272 ?        Sl   11:51   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
renzev  3382  0.0  0.1 470404 12928 ?        Sl   11:56   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
renzev  3395  0.0  0.0 305608  5120 ?        Sl   11:56   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
renzev  3412  0.1  0.2 412324 22276 ?        Sl   11:56   0:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
renzev  3674  0.0  0.0   2568  1664 ?        S    11:56   0:00 bwrap --args 43 xdg-dbus-proxy --args=45
renzev  3675  0.3  0.0 231980  4992 ?        Sl   11:56   0:00 xdg-dbus-proxy --args=45
renzev  4055  0.0  0.0   6560  2304 pts/1    S+   11:56   0:00 grep xdg
```